# Picking randomly $6$ cards from a deck of $52$ cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations

**Exercise :**

> Assume you pick randomly $6$ cards from a normal deck of $52$ cards.
>
> (a) What is the probability of all cards having the same color ? (for example, 6 hearts)
>
> (b) What is the probability of picking $3+3$ cards ? (for example 3 dames and 3 10s)

**Attempt :**

(a)

$$P(a) = \frac{\text{# of ways to have 6 cards that are all hearts }}{\text{# of ways to have 6 cards in general}} = \frac{?}{ \binom{52}{6}} = \dots$$

Is the above elaboration correct ? If so, what is the binomial number for the numerator that I need to set ? I know that there are $13$ hearts in a deck of $52$ cards.

(b)

$$P(b) = \frac{\binom{13}{3}\binom{39}{0}+\binom{13}{3}\binom{39}{0}}{\binom{52}{6}}$$

since we want $3$ out of the $13$ possible types and the rest can be whatever. Is this correct though ?

Sorry if this is elementary but this is my first course of combinatorics/probabilities and having to deal with cards (which I was never interested in) makes it a bit harder.

Comment: For (a): you know there are $13$ hearts, so the number of ways to pick $6$ of them is... $\binom{13}6$. Now don't forget diamonds, clubs and spades.

Comment: @Arthur So, the numerator should be : $$\binom{13}{6}\binom{39}{0}$$ ? What about (b) though ? Is it correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose all 6 cards from either Hearts or Diamonds or Spades or Clubs each of 13 cards. Therefore there will be $4\binom{13}{6}$ different such ways to do that and the corresponding probability is $$P(a)=\dfrac{4\binom{13}{6}}{\binom{52}{6}}$$for the latter probability we first need to choose two different and distinct 4-tuples (such as dames and 10s) in $\binom{13}{2}$ ways and choose $3$ cards from each set which is possible in $\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{3}\binom{4}{3}$ different ways and the probability is $$P(b)=\dfrac{\binom{13}{2}\binom{4}{3}\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{52}{6}}$$

Comment: For (a), why pick **and diamonds** or **and clubs** too ? The question is giving an example of picking $6$ same, like $6$ hearts. From (b), why would one want to pick in such way ? I don't understand the elaboration.

Comment: In many languages, the word "colour" in the context or playing cards actually refers to suits, not to red / black. I suspect that that may be the case here too.

Comment: Well! I thought you mean exactly colors not suits... Thank you dear Arthur i'm gonna fix it.......

Comment: I still don't get something about the 2nd part. Why would it be : $\binom{13}{2}$ and not $2\binom{13}{1}$, since you need 1 of each kind of cards that are $13$ ? What about the $\binom{4}{3}$ part ?

Comment: First you need to choose from which 4-tuples you're gonna pickup 2 sets each of 3 cards. There are 13 such sets e.g. 4 kings, 4 queens, 4 jacks or 4 aces. There are 13 such 4-tuples. Now in how many ways you can choose 2 sets of 4-tuples to choose from? Obviously $\dfrac{13\times 12}{2}$. Also $\binom{4}{3}$ refers to for example choosing 3 queens from 4 each on one suit.